# Bootstrap horizontal scrollable tab panel content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out the horizontal version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298473/7835535. Instead of having the content scroll vertically, I want the content to scroll horizontally.

[Fiddle taken from the original post](http://jsfiddle.net/f3p35v76)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>            
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="test">
                    CONTENT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, could you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can use this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3p35v76/ from the existing question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51n56p94/

You need to add this css

```
.tab-pane{
    width:1000px;

}
.tab-content{
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```